# React.js & tensorflow.js web page can't print result value on the console and html page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tensorflow

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'

function App() {
  const x = [28, 23, 25, 25, 26, 25, 27, 28, 32, 30, 35, 32, 34, 30, 29]
  const y = [23, 25, 25, 26, 25, 27, 28, 32, 30, 35, 32, 34, 30, 29, 26]
  var res;
    
  const model = tf.sequential();
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}));
  model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.001)});

  const xs = tf.tensor2d(x, [15, 1])
    const ys = tf.tensor2d(y, [15, 1])

  model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 1 }).then(() => {
    res = tf.round(model.predict(tf.tensor2d([50], [1, 1])))
    alert(res)
  })
  
  console.log(res)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Result: {res} </h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I want to print tensorflow predict result on a web page made by react.
Line:19 alert(res) is okay but Line:22 console.log(res) print 'undefined'
and Line:26 Result: {res} doesn't print res value.
What's the matter?

Comment: Model.fit is a Promise, so console.log en return are executed before model.fit finish

Answer (score 0):

As we can read on this line `model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 1 }).then(() => {`, `fit` returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

That means the code is asynchronous and your callback will be executed after the `console.log`.

Your could transform your function into an async function to make the code that you want:

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css'
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs'

async function App() {
  const x = [28, 23, 25, 25, 26, 25, 27, 28, 32, 30, 35, 32, 34, 30, 29]
  const y = [23, 25, 25, 26, 25, 27, 28, 32, 30, 35, 32, 34, 30, 29, 26]
    
  const model = tf.sequential()
  model.add(tf.layers.dense({units: 1, inputShape: [1]}))
  model.compile({loss: 'meanSquaredError', optimizer: tf.train.sgd(0.001)})

  const xs = tf.tensor2d(x, [15, 1])
  const ys = tf.tensor2d(y, [15, 1])

  await model.fit(xs, ys, { epochs: 1 })
  const res = tf.round(model.predict(tf.tensor2d([50], [1, 1])))
  
  console.log(res)

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Result: {res} </h1>
    </div>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Note: I have never used `tensorflow.js` so I don't know if there was other errors in your code